# Pass file along with other form details to API in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I am learning angular. I need to POST file along with other form elements. I need help passing them to API. I was able to pass just file onFileselected. Here is my html file:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Load file</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="employeeId">employee id</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input id="employeeId" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='employeeId'>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="userType">user</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select id="userType" class="form-select" formControlName="userType">
              <option class= "dropdown-item" *ngFor="let c of usersTypes" [value]="c.userId">{{ c.userName }}</option>
                          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="file">file</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="file" type="file" class="form-control" formControlName='filefield'  accept=".xls,.xlsx" (change)= "onfileSelected($event)">
            </div>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer" > 
        <div class="btn-toolbar" >
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

TS: This is my typescript file where. I want to post file along with other form data to API.

```
ngOnInit(){

  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    employeeId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    userType:new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   filefield: new FormControl()
  });

onfileSelected(event: Event) {

  const target= event.target as HTMLInputElement;
this.selectedFile = (target.files as FileList)[0];
const formData = new FormData();

if (this.selectedFile) {
formData.append("file",this.selectedFile);

console.log(formData);

}

  onSubmit( ){
       console.log(this.myForm.value);
    this.fileupload.postUpload(this.myForm.value).subscribe(
      ( result)=> { console.log(result)
      }          );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your API access a property called `formData` which accepts a property with type as `MultipartFile[]` or similar to process the data, since the backend details are not shared, this is just an approximate answer!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      employeeId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      userType: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      filefield: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  onfileSelected(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.selectedFile = (target.files as FileList)[0];
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (this.selectedFile) {
      formData.append("file", this.selectedFile);

      console.log(formData);

    }
    this.formData = formData;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const {
      employeeId
      userType
    } = this.myForm.value;
    const params = {
      employeeId,
      userType,
      fileData: this.formData
    }
    this.fileupload.postUpload(params).subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result)
        this.formData = null;
      });

  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Api does accept MultipartFile[] file.

Comment: Thanks Naren I had to change this.myform.reset() since it didnt allow this.formData=null.   also probably because how my api was written, I had to append employeeId and usertype into into formdata and pass it into post request.